# Use awk to count all rows that match 2 header patterns

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this

+++

```
added
PAF1-PAU1 1074704
PAF1-PAZ1 1074704
PAF1-PAM1 1074704
PAF1-PAH1 1074704
PAF1-PAG1 1075154
added
PAX0-PAU1 1074039
PAX0-PAH1 1074039
PAX0-PAM1 1074039
PAX0-PAF1 1074704
PAX0-PAZ0 1074039
PAX0-PAZ1 1074261
deleted
PLX0-PLF2 1074704
PLX0-PLF1 1074040
PLX0-PLZ0 1074262
PLX0-PLV1 1074040
PLX0-PLJ1 1074040
PLX0-PLN1 1074040
deleted
NGG1-NGK1 1073780
NGG1-NGH1 1073780
NGG1-NGJ1 1073780
NGG1-NGM1 1073780
NGG1-NGV1 1073780
NGG1-NGU1 1073780
NGG1-NGQ1 1073780
NGG1-NGN1 1073780
```

+++

What i'm trying to do is group and count everything that is under added and then deleted.

so ideally everything that is added would = 11 and everything that is deleted = 14

I've tried various awk combinations, namely

```
cat file.txt | awk '{count[$1]++} END {for (word in count) print word, count[added]}' |sort
```

but the output shows

```
NGG1-NGH1
NGG1-NGJ1
NGG1-NGK1
NGG1-NGM1
NGG1-NGN1
NGG1-NGQ1
NGG1-NGU1
NGG1-NGV1
PAF1-PAG1
PAF1-PAH1
PAF1-PAM1
PAF1-PAU1
PAF1-PAZ1
PAX0-PAF1
PAX0-PAH1
PAX0-PAM1
PAX0-PAU1
PAX0-PAZ0
PAX0-PAZ1
PLX0-PLF1
PLX0-PLF2
PLX0-PLJ1
PLX0-PLN1
PLX0-PLV1
PLX0-PLZ0
added
deleted
```

Gentlemen I have tried your solutions and it works like it should! Many thanks. I do lastly have one more question I've just encountered. How would you handle the same scenario if the string added was not at the top of the line. For instance -

```
PAF1-PAU1 1074704
PAF1-PAZ1 1074704
PAF1-PAM1 1074704
PAF1-PAH1 1074704
PAF1-PAG1 1075154
added
PAX0-PAU1 1074039
PAX0-PAH1 1074039
PAX0-PAM1 1074039
PAX0-PAF1 1074704
PAX0-PAZ0 1074039
PAX0-PAZ1 1074261
deleted
PLX0-PLF2 1074704
PLX0-PLF1 1074040
PLX0-PLZ0 1074262
PLX0-PLV1 1074040
PLX0-PLJ1 1074040
PLX0-PLN1 1074040
deleted
NGG1-NGK1 1073780
NGG1-NGH1 1073780
NGG1-NGJ1 1073780
NGG1-NGM1 1073780
NGG1-NGV1 1073780
NGG1-NGU1 1073780
NGG1-NGQ1 1073780
NGG1-NGN1 1073780
```

awk 'NF == 1 { ad = $0; next } { m[ad]++ } END { for (prop in m) print prop, m[prop] }' file.txt

```
Now displays
```

5
deleted 14
added 6

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts in your question, keep it up. Could you please wrap your samples in CODE TAGS for better understanding of your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the expected output given the input you posted so we can test a potential solution to see if it works or not.

Comment: If you don't have a header `added` or `deleted` at the first line, then what is the data? `added` or `deleted`? You can look into using `BEGIN` to initiate `ad`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are using the first word as an key in the associate array `count` and at the end loops over all entries and print them, you also try to index the array with the value of the undefined variable `added`.

The below will use either `added` or `deleted` as the key, as continue to update the value with the key until it changes. At the the end loop over the entries to print the key and the count accumulated.

As it seems that the only rows with one field is `added` and `deleted` the following might be sufficient:

```
$ awk 'NF == 1 { prop = $0; next } { cnt[prop]++ } END { for (prop in cnt) print prop, cnt[prop] }' file.txt
deleted 14
added 11
```

If not then the condition `NF == 1` could be changed to something like `/^(added|deleted)$/`

When looping over associate arrays there is no guarantee to output order, it could be `added` first or `deleted` first.

As you might have noticed I have removed the `cat file.txt |` pipe as awk supports files on the command line:

```
awk 'PROGRAM' input_file1 input_file2 ... input_fileN
```

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate using `NR` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
added
PAF1-PAU1 1074704
PAF1-PAZ1 1074704
PAF1-PAM1 1074704
PAF1-PAH1 1074704
PAF1-PAG1 1075154
added
PAX0-PAU1 1074039
PAX0-PAH1 1074039
PAX0-PAM1 1074039
PAX0-PAF1 1074704
PAX0-PAZ0 1074039
PAX0-PAZ1 1074261
deleted
PLX0-PLF2 1074704
PLX0-PLF1 1074040
PLX0-PLZ0 1074262
PLX0-PLV1 1074040
PLX0-PLJ1 1074040
PLX0-PLN1 1074040
deleted
NGG1-NGK1 1073780
NGG1-NGH1 1073780
NGG1-NGJ1 1073780
NGG1-NGM1 1073780
NGG1-NGV1 1073780
NGG1-NGU1 1073780
NGG1-NGQ1 1073780
NGG1-NGN1 1073780
```

then

```
/^[a-z]+$/{if(NR>1){count[header]+=(NR-lastline-1)};lastline=NR;header=$0}END{count[header]+=(NR-lastline);for(x in count){print x ":" count[x]}}
```

will output:

```
deleted:14
added:11
```

Explanation: I assumed header is any non-empty string consisting solely of ASCII lowercase letters and first line is always some header. For every line with header I compute number of lines between current line and previous line with header, then add that value to count array under key which is content of previous line with header. I did so for all but first line. Then in `END` I do to need yet one addition as otherwise lines beyond last line with headers would be ignored. Finally I do print what I stored in `key:value` format.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*